# Where does Task Execution go?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Based on following code, my expectation was that console would emit

- SayTaskHelloCalled
- Task Executing
- SayHelloAfterSleepTask

But task doesn't runs. Only first line emits in console. Please suggest why?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task2 = SayHelloTask();
        var result = task2.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

 public static Task<string> SayHelloTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("SayHelloTaskCalled");
            return  new Task<string>(() => {
                Console.WriteLine("Task Executing");
                return "SayHelloAfterSleepTask";
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a new `Task` using its one of the constructors hands you back a "Cold Task". Meaning that the Task isn't started yet. Since you've never started the Task, you don't see the expected output.

You need to call `Task.Start` to start it. In order to return a "Hot Task"(Started Task), you need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run`.

Following should work:

```
public static Task<string> SayHelloTask()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("SayHelloTaskCalled");
    return  Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("Task Executing");
        return "SayHelloAfterSleepTask";
       });
}
```

If you prefer your Task to be the "Cold Task" itself, then modify your calling code as below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task2 = SayHelloTask();
    task2.Start();//<--Start a "Cold task"
    var result = task2.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. What changes are needed if I wish to start cold-task from calling code.. Let's say for some reason I want the caller to decide when to start the engine :)

Comment: @helloworld Updated my answer. Hope that helps. But I recommend not to use Cold Tasks for public methods. Because almost every .net framework method returns a Task is a Hot Task. Returning a Cold Task creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Oh.. It had a Start().. Pretty Succinct :) Thanks a lot..  Just one additional query.. What specific difference is there in returning Task<T> v/s async Task<T> .. as Task is already background.. My original query is answered though.. thanks

Comment: I answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/async-await-return-task). In short, an async Task will generate a State Machine. Where as other doesn't.