# Task vs async Task

Tags: c#, .net, task

Ok, I've been trying to figure this out, I've read some articles but none of them provide the answer I'm looking for.

My question is: Why `Task` has to return a Task whilst `async Task` doesn't?
For example:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    // Code removed for brevity.

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

As you can see there, that method isn't `async`, so it has to return a Task.

Now, take a look at this one:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    // Code removed for brevity...
    if(user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "username_or_password_incorrect");
        return;
    }

    if(!user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "email_not_confirmed");
        return;
    }

    // Code removed for brevity, no returns down here...
}
```

It uses the `async` keyword, but it doesn't return a Task. Why is that?
I know this may be probably the stupidest question ever.
But I wanna know why it is like this.

Answer (score 14):

`async` is an indicator to the compiler that the method contains an `await`. When this is the case, your method *implicitly* returns a Task, so you don't need to.

Answer (score 9):

The first method is not an asynchronous method. It returns a task, but by the time it returns the task, the entire method would have been done anyway.

The second method is asynchronous. Essentially, your code will execute synchronously until it reaches an `await` keyword. Once it does, it will call the `async` function and return control to the function that called it. Once the `async` function returns its `Task`, the awaited function resumes where it left off. There's more to it than that, and this was a relatively sparse answer.

However, the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) on the `async` keyword should help your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Async methods are different than normal methods. Whatever you return from async methods are wrapped in a Task.
If you return no value(void) it will be wrapped in Task, If you return int it will be wrapped in Task and so on.
Same question : [async await return Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/async-await-return-task)

Comment: I couldn't find this statement in msdn articles; can someone pls paste a reference link to official docs to this