# Task vs async Task when running multiple task in background

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task

Thread synchronization is not important to me. I just want to understand if there is any specific difference. 
So can someone review this code and give me some ideas. All methods are executed in the background as desired I just

<s>**Part 1.**</s>

In Program `DoSomeAsyncStuff()` when removed `async` then

`Task.Run(() => DoSomeAsyncStuff("a"));` will block the execution, so I need async,

Compare `DoSomeAsyncStuff` to `DoSomeAsyncStuffV2` is once implementation preferred over another?

**UPDATE**: Let's focus on

**Part 2.**

whats the difference `private async Task Do..()` vs `private Task Do..()`
based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392684/1818723 I think there could be none, but if you look at both methods implementation, one is awaiting for task to complete and the other is returning the task

```
public class ServiceX
{
    public Task SomeServiceEntryMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Multithreading started");
        Thread.Sleep(1);

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            //I can use this version 
            //var t = DoSomeAsyncStuff(i.ToString());       

            //or I can use this version both seems to have same results
            var t = DoSomeAsyncStuffV2(i.ToString());
            tasks.Add(t);
        }
        //in the calling method I can await for all task to complete the for loop spins a few async tasks
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
    }

    private async Task DoSomeAsyncStuffV2(string text)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (text == "0")
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("test " + text + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

        });
    }

    private Task DoSomeAsyncStuff(string text)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (text == "0")
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("test " + text + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Task.Run(() => DoSomeAsyncStuff("a"));
        //Task.Run(() => DoSomeAsyncStuff("b"));

        //DoSomeAsyncStuffV2("c");
        //DoSomeAsyncStuffV2("d");
        ServiceX x = new ServiceX();
        await x.SomeServiceEntryMethod();
    }

    //private static async void DoSomeAsyncStuff(string text)
    //{
        //Console.WriteLine("test " + text + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    //}

    //private static async void DoSomeAsyncStuffV2(string text)
    //{
        //await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("test " + text + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()));
    //}
}
```

What's the difference?
[image]

Comment: 1. _`Task.Run(() => DoSomeAsyncStuff("a"));` will block the execution_ - it shouldn't block an execution. `Main` will continue execution regardless of that call result.

Comment: Are you sure about that last comment, @Fabio? Aren't you confusing the state machine with the synchronization context?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, StateMachine it is, thanks

Answer (score -1):

The `async` keyword will instruct the compiler to build a state machine with being the code between the beginning of the method' execution flow and the first `await`, the code between any two consecutive `await`s and between the last `await` and the return of the method.

The return type of the method is either `void` if you don't care about the result or if the method completes (beware of this), `Task` if you want to await the execution of the method but don't want to return any value or `Task<T>` if you want to await the execution of the method and return a value of type `T`.

If the method doesn't have the `async` modifier, than it's just a "normal" method.

Comment: but `private Task DoSomeAsyncStuff` doesn't have `async` keyword and runs async, all the methods finish first before `text == "0"` where the thread sleeps. I'm assuming you referred to any method that has a type different than Task

Comment: No it doesn't! It invokes something that runs async and returns the task representing that.

Comment: It does, and I made the proof for you https://github.com/skironDotNet/AsyncBackgroundTask

Comment: No it doesn't, and you proved nothing: https://github.com/skironDotNet/AsyncBackgroundTask/issues/1