# When I call an Async method what return type should I use to indicate success?

Tags: c#

Here's what I have. There's more to the code but I just put in this snippet to make the question smaller.

```
    public async Task GetCards(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await CheckCardAvailability(cts);
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckCardAvailability(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        if (Counts.selectedCardCount == 0)
        {
            CardCountZeroMessages();
            SetMessageView(false);
            await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
            return;
        }
        if (XYX == 0)
        {
            // other code
            await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I just have a simple return here but should I do this differently as the return type is Task? Note that I added the return as I have many of these if conditions and I didn't want to do a lot of if else if else if ..

Comment: `Task<WhatEverYouWant>`

Comment: `async` takes care of creating the `Task`. Since it's a `Task`, rather than a `Task<something>`, it's not going to contain any result.

Comment: Or just Task. If you cancel the wait you'll get an exception. If not, the function succeeded.

Comment: This answer here should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25191745/4636715

Comment: I updated the question to show how it was called.  Perhaps this makes it more clear what i am doing.  Hope so.  Sorry to not have included the calling method originally.

Comment: What's the point of using `Task.Delay` here? It adds a delay *after* the function finished succesfully. This function will fail only if the delay is cancelled. `CheckCardAvailability` is executed *synchronously*. Only the dalye is async

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe that's so the `while(true)` doesn't crash? But I think the two last lines should be moved outside from the `if` statements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - It continually checks every 1/2 second and does different things if the if condition is true or false

Comment: @Alan2 if you intend to poll with an asynchronous delay, pull `Task.Delay` out of `CheckCardAvailability`. `CheckCardAvailability` doesn't seem to perform any async work so it shouldn't be `async Task`. A System.Threading.Timer is another alternative

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - is it possible you give an answer using System.Threading.Timer so I could get an idea how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos, you might consider changing your code to:

```
public async Task GetCards(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CheckCardAvailability(cts);
            await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token); // or something with a timer
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}

private /*async Task*/void CheckCardAvailability(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    if (Counts.selectedCardCount == 0)
    {
        CardCountZeroMessages();
        SetMessageView(false);
        // await Task.Delay moved outside
    }
    if (XYX == 0)
    {
        // other code
        // await Task.Delay moved outside
    }
}
```