# return Task.Run in an async method

Tags: c#, async-await

How would you rewrite `TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync` to avoid the error: Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type `int` rather than `Task<int>`.

```
private static async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation());
}

private static int ComplexCalculation()
{
    double x = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i< 10000000; i++)
    {
        x += Math.Sqrt(x) / i;
    }
    return (int)x;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async await return Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/async-await-return-task)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple; either don't make it `async`:

```
private static Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation());
}
```

or `await` the result:

```
private static async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation());
}
```

(adding the `await` here is more expensive in terms of the generated machinery, but has more obvious/reliable exception handling, etc)

Note: you could also probably use `Task.Yield`:

```
private static async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    return ComplexCalculation();
}
```

(note that what this does depends a lot on the sync-context, if one)

Comment: In what way is the exception handling more obvious/reliable? When I test it, they are the same (other than the `await` version has more lines in the stack trace.)