# Accessing the return value of Task on the same line as await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I had a method SplitInto2DArray that turned a File objects representing a CSV file into a File2DArray class.

File2DArray is a simple class that contains an array for Headers and a 2D array for the body.

```
public class File2DArray
{
    public string[] Headers;
    public string[][] Content;
}
```

To turn an array of File objects into File2DArray objects I did:
`Files.Select(File => File.SplitInto2DArray().Content`

However I made SplitInto2DArray into an async function as it was blocking the thread with numerous large CSV files.
When I did this I had to change the `Select` function but I ran into a problem.

`.Select(async File => await File.SplitInto2DArray().Content`

`SplitInto2DArray` no longer returns a `File2DArray` but a `Task<File2DArray>` which doesn't have the property `Content`.

I could turn it into a multiline lambda but I am interested if there is a way of accessing the output of an `await Task<T>` on the same line as the await.

Comment: This is entirely a guess, but can you do `(await File.SplitInto2DArray()).Content`?
The await has to happen before getting the content.

Comment: Dot has higher precedence than await, so you just need extra parentheses. `(await File.SplitInto2DArray()).Content`

Comment: @RaymondChen @Xtros I had a look at this in  response to @Messenger's answer and adding parentheses around the `await Task<File2DArray>` seems to change the return type of the lambda function to `Task<string[][]>` rather than `string[][]` which is rather strange and I'm not sure why that happens.

Comment: @AlexDobson-Pleming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/async-await-return-task

Comment: I see so declaring the lambda as `async` is causing `Select()` to return `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. However it needs to return `IEnumerable<T>` and using another `Select` with `async Task => await Task` would return another `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` not `IEnumerable<T>`. Is there a way to get a list of values not tasks?

Comment: You can use `Task.WhenAll` to collapse an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` to a `T[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Files.Select(async File => (await File.SplitInto2DArray()).Content)`

There is a pair of parentheses containing `await File.SplitInto2DArray()`.

While the `await` keyword blocks the current thread until the async function finish and return, the `Task<File2DArray>` becomes `File2DArray`.

Maybe it's not an accurate explanation but it should work.

Comment: `Files.Select(async File => (await File.SplitInto2DArray()).Content)` returns type `IEnumerable<Task<string[][]>>` not `IEnumerable<string[][]>`. Possibly this is because .Content is being evaluated as part of the `Task<T>`? I am not sure.

Comment: *"While the await keyword blocks the current thread until the async function finish and return"* - This is not accurate. The rest of the method does not run until the async function finishes, but the thread is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) nuget package to get nice extensions for `IAsyncEnumerable`

```
PM> Install-Package System.Linq.Async
```

And your code will look like

```
var contents = await Files.ToAsyncEnumerable()
    .SelectAwait(async file => await file.SplitInto2DArray())
    .Select(array => array.Content)
    .ToListAsync();
```